# Read write file from Javascript in Xcode project

Tags: javascript, iphone, xcode, file

I am making a iPhone app using JavaScript. I want to open a file as a result file and I need to write some result logs and data from javascript. With the iphone I use to use documentsDirectory to open file and do read/write operations. But now I want to do this in javascript. Now how can I use this documentsDirectory to write a file and access it later from Xcode. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks
Akansha

I am using following youtube api code. I have made a file called youtubeAPI.html and calling this file from objective-c code. It opens the page successfully. Now I want to open a file and write the something everytime it changes it states, and then need to to show that file in the final result from obejective-c. Please tell me how can i do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script>
    //Load player api asynchronously.
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    var done = false;
    var player;
    function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'JW5meKfy3fY',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
    }
    function onPlayerReady(evt) {
        evt.target.playVideo();
    }
    function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
        if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) { // NEED TO ADD FILE OPERATION HERE
            setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
            done = true;
        }
    }
    function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written files in PhoneGap but never accessed it from objective c.
But I'm quite sure that any file written whether in JS or Obj-C it is written in document directory. 
For help you can check these link [PhoneGap file writing](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) and [W3 File api](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).
Examples in PhoneGap is easy to understand and I think it should work as it uses W3 JS file api.

Comment: if I don't want to open the file in objective C again. Then How can I just make and write in file from javascript in xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that I have written to read and write to the file system that works for me. Note that the fileWriter will pass back the absolute path to the file but the file reader needs a relative path hence the getRelativePathToFile method at the bottom.

```
function onPlayerStateChange(evt) {
 if (evt.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) { // NEED TO ADD FILE OPERATION HERE

 PG.saveToDisk('youTubeStateChange.txt', 'on player state change', 
  function (pathToFile){
   alert('file written to ' + pathToFile);
  }
 ); 

 setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
   done = true;
 }
}

// make error codes meaningful
PG.FileErrors = {
 1:     'File not found',
 2:     'Security error',
 3:     'Action Aborted',
 4:     'File not readable',
 5:     'Encoding error',
 6:     'No modification allowed',
 7:     'Invalid state error',
 8:     'Syntax error',
 9:     'Invalid modification error',
 10:    'Quota Exceeded',
 11:    'Type mismatch',
 12:    'Path exists' 
};

// writes a file to the fileSystem 
// and sets the path to the file
// which can be used in the callback
// @param {} fileContent  
// @param {string} fileName  
// @param {function} callback
PG.saveToDisk = function (fileContent, fileName, callback){
 var    pathToFile, 
    accessFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem; 

 // something went wrong..
 function fail (error){
  console.log('-- saveToDisk: error ' + error + ' '  + PG.FileErrors[error.code]); 
 }



// finally write to a file
 function gotFileWriter (writer){
  console.log('-- saveToDisk: gotFileWriter');

  // ..yaay! it worked
  writer.onwrite = function (event){
   if(typeof callback == 'function'){
    console.log('-- saveToDisk: calling back');

    callback.call(this, pathToFile);
   }
  }; 

  // working it..
  writer.write(fileContent);

  delete gotFileWriter;
 }

 // now that we have a location
 // on disk we can write to it..
 function gotFileEntry (fileEntry){
  console.log('-- saveToDisk: gotFileEntry');

  pathToFile = fileEntry.toURI();

  // ..not quite 
  fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);

  delete gotFileEntry;
 }

 // get file for writing
 function getFileSystem (fileSystem){
  console.log('-- saveToDisk: getFileSystem');

  fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);

  delete getFileSystem;
 }


 if(typeof accessFileSystem != 'undefined'){
  console.log('-- saveToDisk: accessed file system');

  accessFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, getFileSystem, fail);

  // clean up as we go to save space in
  // call stack and prevent 'call stack
  // size exceeded' error
  delete accessFileSystem;
 } else {
  console.log('-- saveToDisk: no requestFileSystem so exiting');
 }

};

// get a file at a source from
// disk and pass it to callback
// @param {function} callback
PG.getFromDisk = function (source, callback){
 var    accessFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem;

 // something went wrong..
 function fail (error){
  console.log('-- getFromDisk: error ' + PG.FileErrors[error.code]); 
 }

 //we read it
 // @param {string} method
 //  defaults to text unless image is specified
 function readData (file, method){
  console.log('readDataUrl');

  var   reader = new FileReader(),
    method = method == 'image' ? 'readAsDataURL' : 'readAsText';

  reader.onloadend = function (event){
   if(typeof callback == 'function'){
    console.log('-- getFromDisk: calling back');

    callback.call(this, event.target.result); 
   }
  };

  reader[method](file);
 }

 // what do we do with the file?
 function gotFile (file){
  console.log('-- gotFile');

  readData(file);
 }

 // get the file
 function gotFileEntry (fileEntry){
  console.log('-- gotFileEntry');

  fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
 }

 // get file reader
 function getFileSystem (fileSystem){  
  console.log('-- getFileSystem: ' + source);

  fileSystem.root.getFile(source, null, gotFileEntry, fail);
 }

  // why did the fileSystem cross the road?
  // so it could callback 4 times!
 if(typeof accessFileSystem != 'undefined'){
  accessFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, getFileSystem, fail);
 } else {
  console.log('-- getFromDisk: no requestFileSystem so exiting');
 }

};

// get relative path to saved file
// because that is what the file 
// reader needs
// @param {string} pathToFile
PG.getRelativePathToFile = function (pathToFile){
 if(/localhost|mnt/.exec(pathToFile)){  
  var root = /localhost|mnt/.exec(pathToFile)[0];

  pathToFile = pathToFile.substring(pathToFile.indexOf(root));
  pathToFile = pathToFile.substring(pathToFile.indexOf('/'));
 }

 console.log('-- getRelativePathToFile: pathToFile = ' + pathToFile);

 return pathToFile; 
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by change states? Is it whenever the onPlayerStateChange function is called? 

I have updated the code to show how you could write a file in JavaScript. I am not sure how you would open the file in objective-C but it sounds like you have that worked out already.

Comment: Nops, I havent worked that. Still struggling with this. Need to check what could be done. Thanks for your help though. I will try to see if your code could be used for my purpose or not.

Comment: if I don't want to open the file in objective C again. Then How can I just make and write in file from javascript in xcode project.